# Why does swapping out a = comparison for an unused IN slow down this T-SQL query so much?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Apologies but I can't offer a reproducible example for this. It won't reproduce with a simple example and thus must be related to our data structures and volume: I'm hoping someone can see a pattern here and offer some advice.

We previously had a stored procedure, which felt oddly written to me but worked fine, which ran code equivalent to the following pseudocode:

```
DECLARE @HasResults BIT = 0;

IF 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable t
    WHERE
        t.field1 = @param1
        OR t.field2 = @param2
        OR t.field3 = @param3
        OR t.field4 = @param4) > 0
    SET @HasResults = 1

SELECT @HasResults AS HasResults
```

All of the fields and params were originally integers and in normal usage all but one of them will be NULL. I had to change one of the params to an nvarchar(max) so that it would take a list, which I split with a fairly standard splitting function and then use an IN statement:

```
DECLARE @HasResults BIT = 0;

IF 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable t
    WHERE
        t.field1 = @param1
        OR t.field2 = @param2
        OR t.field3 IN (select ID from fnSplit(@param3))
        OR t.field4 = @param4) > 0
    SET @HasResults = 1

SELECT @HasResults AS HasResults
```

This resulted in the query, in some circumstances, going from a sub-second to over a minute. Now you might expect that from an IN comparison but what baffles me is that if there's data in @param3 it works fine - it's if @param3 is NULL that the query is slow. If you comment out the IN clause, it goes back to sub-second speed.

The splitting function isn't the problem here - it's very fast and I've experimented with it but nothing improves.

To further confuse me I discovered that you can significantly improve the situation by removing that unnecessary IF statement. This takes about 10 seconds to run, which is much slower than the original query but much faster than using the IF:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable t
    WHERE
        t.field1 = @param1
        OR t.field2 = @param2
        OR t.field3 = @param3
        OR t.field4 = @param4
```

Why is this query running so much slower when I try and split a NULL value and use the results in an IN statement, and why does the IF have such an impact?

EDIT: split function as requested:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit](
    @sInputList VARCHAR(MAX) 
  , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(MAX) = ','
) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(MAX))

BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(MAX)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT  
 @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
  @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

 IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
  INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
 END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList
RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: `fn_split` isn't a built-in function, so I would expect that SQL to error; user-defined functions **must** be schema qualified. What is the definition of `fn_split`? Why aren't you using `STRING_SPLIT`, or a table type parameter?

Comment: Also T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well.

Comment: Also, you don't actually need the `IF` at all, you can just assign the value straight to the `bit`: `@HasResults = COUNT(*)`. If the `COUNT` returns `0` then 0 will be assigned, however, for any other integer value, then `1` would be assigned.

Comment: @Larnu we're running SQL 2016 where string_split isn't available. In the actual sproc, the function is properly schema-qualified.

Comment: *"we're running SQL 2016 where string_split isn't available"* This is incorrect; it was added in SQL Server 2016.

Comment: @Larnu I know we don't need the IF - this wasn't my code originally, I just left it alone as it seemed to work fine. I can probably fix the problem simply by removing the IF as a ~10 second operation is fine for what this needs to do. But I'd really like to know why the IF and the IN make such a colossal difference here.

Comment: @Larnu well trying it yields a 'Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'' error

Comment: What is the compatibility level of the database? To use [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) it must be 130 or higher. *"STRING_SPLIT requires the compatibility level to be at least 130. When the level is less than 130, SQL Server is unable to find the STRING_SPLIT function."*

Comment: @Larnu 110 - worth noting that I'm a .net developer not a DBA

Comment: You can use `exists` instead of `count` here. Should be faster.

Comment: Can you upgrade the compatibility? 110 is SQL Server 2012 and as 2016 has been out for ~7 years, it's really past time you should have updated the level by now. Also, we still need the definition of that function if you can't.

Comment: Also I would suggest instated if `fnSplit(@param3)` you take in param3 as a table parameter.

Comment: @Magnus I'm passing in param3 as an nvarchar(max) altho the split function returns a table - I'll post it shortly and try EXISTS

Comment: @Larnu I've added the split function

Comment: Well there's your problem, the function; it's a multi-line table value function that uses a `WHILE`. mlTVF's , and `WHILE` loops are both known to perform very poorly; combine those and you end up with a performance disaster I'm afraid. I cannot more strongly recommend you switch to an inline table value function that uses a set-based solution such as a Tally or XML splitter (*not* an rCTE splitter). Alternatively, use a CLR splitter. Ideally, however, upgrade the compatibility level and just use `STRING_SPLIT`.

Comment: @Larnu so it's a collision between the sproc and the function? Run by itself with a null value, the function is super quick but I appreciate that using it inside a sproc will change the query plan. I've asked the DBAs about the compatibility level.

Comment: No, the problem is that function, `fnsplit`; it's a performance disaster. *Don't* use that function, it's awful.

Comment: @Larnu I appreciate what you're saying about WHILE loops, but if I run SELECT ID FROM fnSplit(NULL) in the database, it's so fast that it doesn't even register a time. So it can't be that function by itself that's slowing things down, right?

Comment: No, it is. Of that, I am certain. I would not be surprised if SQL Server is executing the function multiple times because the way mlTVFs work, so `SELECT ID FROM dbo.fnSplit(NULL)` isn't even a comparable test.

Comment: @Larnu well I just tried it with an XML-based split and it's actually taking even longer. Up to 2 minutes now and no result.

Comment: I would, personally, suggest using [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function). That is uses a `varchar(8000)` is **by design** *do not* change that. If you need more than 8,000 characters, switch to CLR or use `STRING_SPLIT`.

Comment: @Larnu a table function does not need a schema qualified prefix. Only scalar functions requires it to distinguish between integrated functions (does delivered with MS SQL Server) and UDF.

Comment: You're right, @SQLpro , I had forgotten that distinction as I *always* schema qualify.

Comment: @Larnu OK, sadly I can't try that out as I can only replicate this issue on pre-production and I don't have create rights on that Db. I'll have to ask a Dba to add it to test it.

Comment: @Larnu me too... I always qualified everything and forbid the use of dbo for developers....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding why a scalaire UDF or a multi-instruction table can kill performances is very simple.

UDF are Transact SQL that is a interpreted language. Not a compiled one. So the function will be call on every row. This had 3 consequences :

- executing the function for every rows (RBAR effet)
- forbid any parallel processing because of potential side effects
- forbid the use of indexes, because indexes cannot be used when data is transformed

So if you want performances, avoid using UDF when there is another solution.

You can use instead STRING_SPLIT which I think is the fastest or XML operations.

In fact, in queries, that operates as "sets" and not on every values, any use of anything that have an iterative process will kill all performances. Recursive queries includes....

Comment: I did try using an XML operation instead. I stopped the query after 10 minutes with no results returned, whereas our extant split function delivered results in a minute.